# Why do fully qualified domain names have to have an "extension"?

Tags: http

Why there is `.com, .net, ...` extensions still exist? Are they there just because of historical reasons, or they are usefull for some (speed?) reason?

For parsing (from the point of view of humans) we are already using protocol prefix (http, https...). We could use both `http://example` and `https://example` format or more clearly `www.example` and `wwws.example`

Comment: They are there because there is an actual consortium that dictates the usage of those suffixes.  You can't just go creating your own "extension" unless it's approved.  And "www" is increasingly falling out of use altogether.  The prefix you speak of is a protocol.  That's why it's devided from the rest.

Comment: OK. So how do you tell the difference between what now would be `http://example.com` and `http://example.net` and `http://example.edu`, all of which might be totally unrelated sites owned by different entities, when under your plan they would all be just `http://example`? You'd also be cutting a substantial portion of the domain names out of existence (now instead of many separate `example` domains, there's one).

Comment: I'll add that to my answer... (see below.)

Comment: @KenWhite: Now there are 4 entities have 4 domains: com, net, edu, example. They are all OK technically. They all could have subdomain like `www` (`www.com, www.net, www.edu, www.example`) or `example` (`example.com, example.net, example.edu, example.example`)

Comment: @durbnpoisn: I meant "technically". I know technical details about http and https which stand for protocol and www is just a subdomain. But we could use any subdomain for any protocol we like. I meant "writing `://` seems hard to write sometimes, so we could use plain dot for indicating protocol (or any other sign, like we use `@` for `mx`)"

Comment: Probably not without getting everyone in the world to agree to the change of symbols.  Which is unlikely because those symbols mean stuff behind the scenes.  That's why it hasn't changed in like 40 years.

Comment: Why do you think 'www' and 'wwws' are an improvement over 'http' and 'https'? You're replacing '://' with '.', but most people don't type the 'http://' anyway; you type 'example.com' into the browser address bar and the browser takes care of the rest, and the majority of the time the "average user" isn't typing anything, but is either clicking a link or copy/pasting.

Comment: @durbnpoisn: No one needs to agree with this "proposal?", as more domain names come into stage, this "proposal" would get implemented by itself. For example, if I have xyz.com domain and I want to get xyz instead, I could "buy" all www.xyz, ftp.xyz, ...xyz addresses. Some day .abc will become available and so on...

Comment: I thought www and wwws are kind of improvement because people are familiar with these "www" prefix. And no, I am (and I advice my friends) using "https" prefix because nowadays (as web browsers are not having a good precaution yet) ssl striping attack is easy to achieve.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm out of this one.  Both @Ken White and I have given you good, real world examples why your suggestion makes no sense.  In short, you're suggesting to change a long existing implementation.  One that has far reaching purposes beyond what the percieved syntax is.

Comment: And suggesting changing that long existing implementation for absolutely no benefit or gain, especially since you are (and you are "advicing your friends" to) use the "https" prefix, and now you want to drop it and the domain extension as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am exapanding this as an answer because, perhaps, people really don't know what all that stuff means.

A URL is broken into two parts:  Protocol and domain.

The protocol is so your browser (or other client) knows how to handle the transfer.  And it's not just HTTP and HTTPS.  There are many protocols like, FTP, SSH, etc...

The domain needs to be approved, usually by region.  If your site exists in Turkey, you will not be able to get a domain with a .uk domain, because it's not in the UK.  There may be ways around it, but that's the general idea.

The .COM, .NET, etc...  Exist to help, in some way, determine what a site is.  Network, government, education, country, etc...  So, yes, they are absolutely still in use.  And there is no reason that should change any time soon.

On top of that, attempting to use a bizarre formed domain like. site.comli.com, will have to be resolved by your server because that is not an actual approved domain name.  And even though your server will serve it up, it will be flagged by most firewalls and security systems as suspicious.

The variations on domain names like .EDU, .ORG, .CO, etc...  They are individually bought and owned.  They could be the same person that owns them, or literally anyone else.  You could own the .COM version of your domain, but not be able to buy .NET version because someone else already owns it.  This has happened.  This is also the reason that when you buy a domain, the seller normally asks if you want to buy all available variations at the same time.  A few of my clients own 5 different versions of their domain that all redirect to the .COM for exactly this reason.

Comment: I agree that they are there for classifying the selling procedure (in terms of required documents) in the first place. Then there are lots and lots of top level domains produced nowadays just for making some more money.

Comment: You are correct.  To make matters worse, because people know this, they poach those names from people who SHOULD be the rightful owners, and either sell them at a ransom, or just run them as ad revenue generators.  Could you imagine if Verizon lost Verizon.net, and someone statched it up?!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, any domain name that does not end in a period is subject to treatment as a relative domain. `http://example`, if your local machine is set up so, could refer to `http://example.mydomain.net`. By convention, nobody uses `.com` et al. as part of their domain (name your server `myserver.com.mydomain.net` would be somewhat frowned upon), so it's generally safe to assume that a domain name that ends in a well-known top-level domain but not a period is not a relative domain.